# Global new operator call syntax

Tags: c++, new-operator

Why the function with this signature

```
void* operator new (std::size_t size);
```

Cant be called in code like this

```
void* mem = new(100);
```

But rather it must be called like this

```
void mem = ::operator new(100);
```

Comment: The name of the function is not `new`, but `operator new`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keyword `new` and `operator new` are different things.

Keyword `new` does:

1. Call `operator new` to allocate the memory. It can be overloaded for the type being allocated. [Keyword `new` accepts optional arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) that get passed to `operator new`, this allows for placement `new` and non-throwing `new` syntax, see [`#include <new>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/new).
2. Invoke the constructor of the object.
3. If the constructor throws, invoke the corresponding `operator delete` to free the memory. Note that if that `operator delete` is not accessible (not public), then `new` fails at compile time because `operator delete` cannot be called if the constructor throws and memory would be lost.

Keyword `new` cannot be overloaded, it always does these steps. This is `operator new` from step 1 what can be overloaded, normally along with `operator delete` from step 3.

In other words, `X* p = new X(a, b, c);` under the hood does something like (pseudo code):

```
X* p = static_cast<X*>(X::operator new(sizeof(X))); // 1. allocate memory
try { 
    p->X(a, b, c); // 2. invoke the constructor
}                              
catch(...) { 
    X::operator delete(p); // 3. free the memory if the constructor throw
    throw; 
}
```

In the above, if X does not overload its `operator new`, it is the global `::operator new` that gets called. Note that `X::operator new` is implicitly static if overloaded.

Comment: So actually **operator new** isn’t an operator overload?Because new is a keyword and not operator **or** it's a function?
Or is there any difference of these two at all?

Comment: `operator new` can be overloaded. Maxim said exactly that in his answer.

Comment: "Keyword `new` cannot be overloaded, it always does these steps" is not correct. There is the placement new which does not perform memory allocation.

Comment: @cmaster placement new is enabled by overloading `operator new` to not allocate the memory. This is why you need to `#include <new>` with that overload to enable placement new. Keyword `new` behaviour remains unchanged.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Precisely, it's overloaded, and it doesn't always allocate memory...

Comment: @cmaster Keyword `new` cannot be overloaded. It passes its optional arguments to `operator new` which is overloaded to enable placement `new` syntax.

Comment: One more question in your pseudo code you have 
X::operator new
So it's a X member function.So the compiler defines this function which simple allocates raw memory?
I ask this because as I know its not in the "special or implicit"
members of a class.

Comment: @LanPac If `X` does not overload its `operator new`, it is the global `::operator new` that gets called.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin You said if the constructor throws then the operator delete is called but what I am doing wrong or understanding wrong in the following [code](http://ideone.com/eNBhmK)
Shouldn’t at least "My delete was called" be printed

Comment: @LanPac It does call your `operator delete` if you add an exception handler around `main()`, see [this](http://ideone.com/CWaGFz).

Comment: Yeah but shouldn’t that be done automatically from the compiler around the line
MyClass* arr = new MyClass(); 
because of the keyword new.

I understand that it works if I put try catch.. but as you said in the pseudo code
the new keyword does this already.

Comment: @LanPac C++2013 §5.3.4.8 _If the new-expression terminates by throwing an exception, it *may* release storage by calling a deallocation function_. I guess if the exception is unhandled then the program is going to terminate anyway and there is little point in deallocating memory.

Comment: So there may not exist necessarily a try catch around the  constructor call in your pseudo code point.
That is my concern.And in my compiler at least there is not one?
And also thanks for your responses.

Comment: @LanPac Actually, the more appropriate is §5.3.4.18: _If any part of the object initialization described above terminates by throwing an exception and a suitable deallocation function can be found, the deallocation function is called to free the memory in which the object was being constructed, after which the exception continues to propagate in the context of the new-expression._

Comment: @LanPac When an exception is not handled it does not unwind the stack with modern compilers. That probably means that calling `operator delete` is done from a destructor of a local guard object, not using `try`/`catch`/`throw`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a profound syntactical reason for this: placement new. With placement new, you can call a constructor without allocating memory for it. It's syntax is this:

```
#include <new>
Foo* foo = new(bufferPointer) Foo();
```

Obviously, part of this is the precise syntax you tried to call `::operator new()`...